# Spring boot graphql-java and subscriptions

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

The following example https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-subscription-example which use's graphql-java for subscriptions over a websocket.

How can the same idea be done within the spring version? GraphQLSubscriptionResolver needs to return a publisher but I am unable to work out how this can then be used with a web socket.

The example above seems fine within a none spring version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good friend of mine has made an example in his [github repository](https://github.com/yarinvak/annotation-test).
The code is not the nicest (because it was for our own personal needs) but it is a nice example

Have fun

Comment: This example uses the graphql-java-annotations library, but the spring and subscription parts should be the same as if it used graphql-java

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://github.com/estebes/graphql-subscriptions-websockets) a port of the graphql-java example using [GraphQL-SPQR](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr) with Spring Boot. I'll soon merge it into the [GraphQL-SPQR samples project](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples).

Same as with the other answer, while it uses GraphQL-SPQR to generate the schema, the Spring and websockets bit is the same as you'd have with graphql-java directly.

There's now a new and somewhat [more realistic example](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter-sample) using [GraphQL SPQR Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter). It publishes updates when a relevant mutation runs.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a workshop in which you can learn how to implement the subscription operations.

http://graphql-java.wesovilabs.com

Let me know If you have any doubt

I hope you find it useful!
Thanks

Comment: It's better to include the gist here, and the link as an extra.